# Keep Word Art arrow shapes behind text when grouping?

Tags: microsoft-word, troubleshooting, charts, shapes

I'm using Word Art shapes to create charts with text boxes overlaid on arrows. I cannot figure out how to:

1. Group the text boxes and arrows so that the boxes *always* appear on top.

Nor can I:

2. Successfully troubleshoot a group when the arrows come forward.

I've attached an image that demonstrates the problem. The shapes are in groups-of-groups. Before the current group configurations, I tried many more. In every case, the box-arrow combination looks as it should until I create the final group.

I'm hoping the problem (and the fix) has something to do with a precise sequence of steps that, if repeated exactly in any grouping situation, will give the desired results (i.e., always keep object A on top of object B).

In case it helps:

- I'm working with Word 2010.
- I am not using the canvas, and prefer to not use the canvas.
- The boxes are filled with solid white.
- I used the Send to Front/Back options to create the initial desirable results.
- The final grouping is when it breaks.

[image: group-and-tshoot-arrows-and-boxes]

Comment: I replicate your problem and there is no way that you use the send to back on the arrows without them being sent behind even after grouping them with their captions. http://imgur.com/a/xjrgy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider taking advantage of Word's SmartArt feature (available on the **Insert** tab), because it's intended for exactly this type of thing. There's even a **Process** category for showing process flows. The SmartArt will take care of all the arrows for you, and you'll still have lots of control over the appearance of the chart (font, colors, and so on).

Comment: Perfect solution. I discounted using SmartArt because I assumed I would be held hostage to only the SmartArt shapes; i.e., I would not be able to add WordArt shapes for annotations. My assumption was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You must select the text box and right click / secondary click and select `Bring to front` to bring text box to the front.

Similarly you can select arrow and right click / secondary click and select `Send to back` to send arrow to the back.

More Information [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-a-text-box-WordArt-or-shape-dab7e591-bd7b-4dbc-a8e9-7c90a8de3a1f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

And to group/ungroup you can follow the documentation from [Microsoft here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Group-or-ungroup-shapes-pictures-or-other-objects-a7374c35-20fe-4e0a-9637-7de7d844724b)